# Connection issue python with Cassandra

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to fetch data from Cassandra cluster. There is a issue it some time fetches few rows and some times no row.
I am using Python 3.8.5 and latest DataStax Python driver.
Below is the code

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
cluster = Cluster(['xx.xx.x.xx','xx.xx.x.xx','xx.xx.x.xx'])
session = cluster.connect('keyspace')

query = "SELECT * from table  ALLOW FILTERING"  # Allow Filtering is for test

statement = SimpleStatement(query)
for user_row in session.execute(statement):
    print(user_row)
```

The whole statement some time give some result but some time no result.
I have enable trace as suggested to see the execution below is the result

```
0:00:00.000150 Parsing SELECT * from table ALLOW FILTERING
0:00:00.000271 Preparing statement
0:00:00.000425 Computing ranges to query
0:00:00.000654 Submitting range requests on 769 ranges with a concurrency of 1 (0.0 rows per range expected)
0:00:00.001804 Submitted 1 concurrent range requests
0:00:00.001839 Executing seq scan across 0 sstables for (min(-9223372036854775808), min(-9223372036854775808)]
0:00:00.001924 Read 0 live rows and 0 tombstone cells
```

Comment: what is consistency level, what replication factor & number of nodes. also try to perform repair

Comment: When you say its not fetching rows is it timing out? Can you also post your Cassandra and driver version and your table schema? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexOtt the consistency level is the default ie ONE.